# Count sum of column where month from d-m-Y date format laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, where-clause

I have two columns called price and date, so i want to sum the total of price where the month is 01:

```
 price |   date
-------------------
200    | 01-01-2022
100    | 09-01-2022
400    | 01-03-2022
120    | 01-06-2022
```

Here my code:

```
$total = Products::whereMonth('date', '=', 1)->sum('price');
```

But its not showing any data its only showing 0

Comment: I imagine the issue is that `whereMonth` expects `Y-m-d`, which is the far more standard date format. Are you able to make that change?

Comment: @JacobMulquin No i cant change the format there

Comment: In your date format parse it back to a normal format, which you can handle with Carbon. Then through Carbon find that first month. After you have a proper date, the rest you can do with Eloquent. Also ... there's a `MONTH` function in SQL, but then you'd have to use raw sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Because you cannot change the format of things, we have to selectRaw from the database:**

- Step 1) Is to parse the date using your format `"%d-%m-%Y"` you may read more on `str_to_date` function from: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp
- Step 2) we get the month from the parsed date
- Step 3) we assign the parsed date as "modified_date" or whatever you
  like to rename it as.
- Step 4) we select and sum based on the result.

**This should be the final result:**

```
$products = Products::selectRaw('*, month(str_to_date(date, "%d-%m-%Y")) as modified_date')->get();

$total = $products->where('modified_date', 1)->sum('price'));
```

**Result:**

```
300
```

Now you can search by `months 1 -> 12` while maintaining the model & all relationship loading date for other usage.

Comment: Thank you this is working perfectly, now what if i only need to show results for the current year only.

Comment: @sally sorry for the delay, replace the word **"month"** with any of the following **day() / month() / year()** and you will arrive to similar conclusions, because what you care about is the **str_to_date() function**, this is how it will parse the date

Comment: like this ```$products = Products::selectRaw('*, year(str_to_date(date, "%d-%m-%Y")) as modified_date')->get();```

Answer (score 0):

Using DB raw query ,First convert string date to MySQL date format using `STR_TO_DATE` method and then use `MONTH` function to add condition to select month based result.

```
 Products::where(DB::raw("(MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%m-%y')))"),1)->sum('price')
```

Also for reusable purpose you can use laravel [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#local-scopes)

in Product model  add below method

```
public function scopeByMonth($query,$month)
{
   $query->where(DB::raw("(MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%m-%y')))"),$month);
}
```

and query will be

```
Products::byMonth(1)->sum('price');
```